# How to configure a user in sudoers such that the user can install app and can't access a specified directory

Tags: sudo, privileges

I want to add a user to sudoers, such that the user can do anything in root permission but:

1. The user **can't** use mount command;
2. The user **can't** access(read or write) to directory /home/protecteddir;

thanks you all very much for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

To restrict the sudoers from mounting, modify your sudoers file as in,

```
#limit users in group 'sudo' from mounting
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL, !MOUNT
```

To protect a directory from a sudoer, you can try setting using ACL, further information can be found here,

> I am not sure this will work since sudo is almost a root access

[Setting Access ACLs](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-acls-setting.html)

Comment: Preventing calls to `mount` does not prevent mounting. You'd have to prevent the `mount` system call, which sudo can't do. ACL won't do anything against root.